# Why Android CDD specifies audio input sensitivity at 90dB SPL instead of usual 94dBSL?

Tags: android

Why Android CDD specifies audio input sensitivity at 90dB SPL instead of usual 94dBSL?
I suppose test signal is sinewave, no?
Thanks in advance

Comment: probably a link to the CCD that you're specifying may be helpful instead of a contextless question :)

Comment: oops :) Chapter 5.4.2. Capture for Voice Recognition in this Link : https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#5_4_audio_recording